# Collection of poems by Yehuda HaLevi

Tags: sources-mekorot, product-recommendation, song-poetry, yehuda-halevi

Where can I find a printed book with a collection of poems by Yehuda HaLevi?

Ideally this book should (in order of importance):

- Be available to an American consumer
- Include the original Hebrew
- Include commentary in English. Hebrew, or in a less-ideal world, Spanish.
- Include an English translation
- Look nice

[This one](http://nextbookpress.com/books/1589/the-selected-poems-of-yehuda-halevi/) would be great if it were printed. (Hat tip @GershonGold)

Answer (score 4):

http://hebrewbooks.org/38215 is a book of Hebrew poems by Rabbi Yehuda Halevi

Comment: Cool, and +1, but I'd prefer something printed.

Comment: You can print it as long as you include attribution and notice of the license. See here: hebrewbooks.org/media/terms.html

Comment: http://nextbookpress.com/books/1589/the-selected-poems-of-yehuda-halevi/ & http://www.sunypress.edu/p-3072-ninety-two-poems-and-hymns-of-y.aspx

Comment: Can you speak to the quality of the SUNY Press one?

Comment: Here is a preview http://books.google.com/books?id=VkszCiNlIfIC&printsec=frontcover&dq=poems+of+yehudah+halevi&hl=en&sa=X&ei=glXtUdyOHYP7qAHNzoDwAg&ved=0CDQQuwUwAA

Comment: @Yirmeyahu Thanks.  Looks like no Hebrew.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman: you can also order a printed copy through hebrewbooks.org: http://www.publishyoursefer.com/reprints/id/HB-38215 - The quality will only be as good as the scanned version, however.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good one:

Song of the Distant Dove:
[http://www.amazon.com/The-Song-Distant-Dove-Pilgrimage/dp/0195315421](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0195315421)

All of the bullet points are true (with the last subject to opinion)

Answer (score 1):

Two wonderful collections:

1. [Selected Poems of JEHUDAH HALEVI](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Selected-Poems-Jehudah-Halevi-HEBREW-ENGLISH-/371366899592?hash=item5677312f88)* (translated into English by [Nina Salaman](https://jwa.org/encyclopedia/article/salaman-nina-ruth-davis)); Jewish Publication Society 1928
2. THE LITURGICAL POETRY OF RABBI YEHUDA HALEVI by [Dov Jarden](https://he.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91_%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%93%D7%9F) (שירי הקדש לרבי יהודה הלוי); four volumes

The second collection is probably the most comprehensive collection of HaLevi's poems, except they are without English translation. Barring this fact, otherwise they both meet all five criteria.

*Alternative link [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0827600585)